# Need help on debug the Google Script for google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I find the code on YT @ Think Stocks Channel. I followed the tutorial and double check the code for any errors. Basically the script does if I bought new stock like AMD and I do not have it on my currently Portfolio. It auto add into the summary sheet for it. But if I already have a stock, it is just add into currently stock name. Same thing w/ Sell, if want to sell the stock, it is suppose to subtract from the currently stock that i have; however, does not work for the function at all.
If you guys want me  to share the spreadsheet, feel free to let me know. I can shares it w/ you guys.
https://imgur.com/a/H3s0nFU

```
function generateTrade(stockQuant, stockPrice, action){
  return {
    shares: stockQuant,
    price: stockPrice,
    action: action
  };
}

function generateFifo(security, actions, quantity, price){
  let portfolio = new Map ();
  for(var i = 0; i<security.length; i++){

    let ticker = security[i].toString();
    let action = actions[i].toString();
    let stockQuant = Number(quantity[i]);
    let stockPrice = Number(price[i]);
    let trade = generateTrade(stockQuant, stockPrice, action);


    if(action == "Buy" || action.toUpperCase() == "DRIP"){
      let activeTrades = portfolio.get(ticker);
      if(activeTrades == null){
        portfolio.set(ticker, [trade]);
      } else {
        activeTrades.push(trade);
      }
    }


    if (action.toUpperCase() == "SPLIT"){
      let activeTrades = portfolio.get(ticker);
      let ratio = quantity[i].toString().split(":");
      activeTrades = activeTrades.map((trade) =>{
        trade.shares = trade.shares * ratio[0];
        trade.price = trade.price / ratio[0];
        trade.shares = trade.shares * ratio [1];
        trade.price = trade.price / ratio [1];
    });
    }


    if(action == "Sell"){
      let activeTrades = portfolio.get(ticker);
      let precision = 5;
      if (activeTrades != null){
        let sharesToSell = Number(Number(trade.shares).toFixed(precision));
        while (sharesToSell > 0){
          sharesToSell = Number(Number(sharesToSell).toFixed(precision));
          if (activeTrades.length > 0 ){
            let itemToSell = activeTrades[0];
            itemToSell.shares = Number(Number(itemToSell).toFixed(precision));
            if(itemToSell.shares == sharesToSell){
              sharesToSell = 0;
              activeTrades.splice(0,1);
            }
            else if(itemToSell.shares < sharesToSell) {
              sharesToSell -= itemToSell / shares;
              activeTrades.splice(0,1);
            }
            else {
              itemToSell.shares -= sharesToSell;
              sharesToSell = 0;
            }
          }
        }
        if (activeTrades.length == 0){
          portfolio.delete(ticker);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return portfolio;
}

function myPositions(security, actions, quantity,price){
  let portfolio = generateFifo(security, actions, quantity, price);
  let returnArry = [];
  portfolio.forEach((value, key) => {
    let shares = 0;
    let totalCost = 0;
    let avgPrice = 0;

    value.map(trade => {
      shares += trade.shares;
      totalCost += trade.shares * trade.price;
    });
    avgPrice = totalCost / shares;
    returnArry.push([key, shares, avgPrice]);
  });
  return returnArry;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the testing portion of your code and also the expected result and, in your case the error output your are getting.

Comment: Please consider providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide a more relevant title - one which summarizes the problem. Also, don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask].